# Error 1064 en MySQL en ciclo FOR

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS crear_recibos()
BEGIN
declare xCodigo int;  
    DECLARE
            fFecha date;

DECLARE
    honorarios DECIMAL (10, 2);

DECLARE
    total DECIMAL (10, 2);
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
    FOR contrato IN (
        SELECT
            a.idContratos,
            a.deposito,
            a.fecha_crea,
            a.cuota,
            a.seguro,
            a.agua,
            a.honorarios,
            a.idpropietario,
            a.idinquilino,
            a.idpropiedad,
a.propietario_agua,
a.propietario_seguro
        FROM
            contratos a
        WHERE
            a.estado = 1;
    ) DO
    

SET honorarios = contrato.cuota *(contrato.honorarios / 100);


SET total = contrato.cuota + contrato.seguro + contrato.agua;


SET fFecha = NOW();

INSERT INTO recibos (
    idContrato,
    fecha_crea,
    mes,
    ano,
    fecha_vencimiento,
    idpropietario,
    idinquilino,
    idpropiedad,
    cuota,
    seguro,
    agua,
    honorarios,
    total,
cobrado,fecha_cobro
)
VALUES
    (
        contrato.idContratos,
        fFecha,
        UPPER(MONTHNAME (fFecha)),
        YEAR (fFecha),
        DATE_ADD(fFecha, INTERVAL 10 DAY),
        contrato.idpropietario,
        contrato.idinquilino,
        contrato.idpropiedad,
        contrato.cuota,
        contrato.seguro,
        contrato.agua,
        honorarios,
        total,
"NO",DEFAULT

    );

 
  set xCodigo= @@IDENTITY;
INSERT INTO detalle_recibo(descripcion,valor,idContrato,idrecibo,propietario) VALUES ("VALOR DE CUOTA",contrato.cuota,contrato.idContratos,xCodigo,"NO");
INSERT INTO detalle_recibo(descripcion,valor,idContrato,idrecibo,propietario) VALUES ("VALOR DE AGUA",contrato.agua,contrato.idContratos,xCodigo,(CASE contrato.propietario_agua WHEN 'SI' THEN "NO" ELSE "SI" END));
INSERT INTO detalle_recibo(descripcion,valor,idContrato,idrecibo,propietario) VALUES ("VALOR DE SEGURO",contrato.seguro,contrato.idContratos,xCodigo,(CASE contrato.propietario_seguro WHEN 'SI' THEN "NO" ELSE "SI" END));
INSERT INTO detalle_recibo(descripcion,valor,idContrato,idrecibo,propietario) VALUES ("VALOR DE HONORARIOS",honorarios,contrato.idContratos,xCodigo,"NO");

END FOR;


END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Y me da error de sintaxis en el FOR:

**1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOR contrato IN (...**

El caso es que uso MySQL 8, pero no entiendo porque no funciona.

Comment: Hasta dónde he podido ver, en mySQL no existe el ciclo `for`. ¿De dónde has sacado la sintaxis?

Comment: No recuerdo de donde saque la sintaxis. Pero tengo la misma bd en otro servidor..quizas MariaDB si lo soporta.

Comment: El [FOR](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/for/) es soportado en MariaDB (>= 10.3) pero no en MySQL.

Comment: MariaDB != MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependiendo de los resultados esperados y de cada caso en particular, se puede "emular" un FOR en MySQL

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP`()
BEGIN
    declare result VARCHAR(255) default '';
  declare x INT default 0;
  SET x = 1;

  WHILE x <= 5 DO
    SET result = CONCAT(result,x,',');
    SET x = x + 1;
  END WHILE;

  select result;

END

-- Resultado: 1,2,3,4,5
```

O también con

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP2`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
  DECLARE result VARCHAR(255);
  SET x = 5;
  SET result = '';

  REPEAT
    SET result = CONCAT(result,x,',');
    SET x = x - 1;
    UNTIL x <= 0
  END REPEAT;

  SELECT result;
END

-- Resultado: 5,4,3,2,1
```